# Remember desktop state after reboot

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, expose, command-line

Does anyone know if desktop switching can be done programatically? Exposé activation and deactivation? I know of the `screencapture` command for the last part of my proposed solution.

---

I would like to be able to restore my desktop work environment after a reboot. I have one idea how to do this.

**Reason**: I reboot every 2 - 4 weeks. I have 9 virtual desktops, each with a few to a dozen windows and applications. After a computer reboot it feels like a brain reboot and takes a few days to get everything back.

**Concept**: Manually prior to a planned reboot, or perhaps once a day via cron in case of accidental reboot or system freeze, I'd like to somehow capture the system state in order make recovery post-reboot easier.

**Ideal Solution**: I prefer the CLI. My ideal solution would be a text file of open files on each desktop, and terminal windows on each desktop, and what folder those terminal windows are in. I could then write a script that would go to desktop 1, open all the PDFs there in Preview, open all the `.m` files in AquaMacs, and open the terminals and `cd` them to the correct folder, etc. Repeat for each desktop.

I think AppleScript could easily tell me what PDFs are open in Preview.app, but I don't think it can tell me what desktop they are on. Same with Terminal.app

**Proposed Solution**: Screenshots of each Desktop while in Exposé mode.

Is there a way to script switching from Desktop #1 through Desktop #9, where at each Desktop, it activates Exposé and takes a screenshot?

Now, after a reboot, I can at least go to a folder, open the 9 screenshots, and manually see what application and what files were open where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you ever try [Relaunch](http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/) application:

[Relaunch](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/30839) saves you time by taking Snapshots of which applications you are using, and starts them back up for you. Think of it as a launcher on steroids that lets you switch between work contexts with one click.

you can take a snapshot before restart your system and after that double click on the snapshot you created then it restored all your files and application you worked on.

Comment: First test was buggy - deleted comment. Relaunch is a basic start in the right direction. It only opens Preview.app, none of the PDFs. It doesn't know anything about virtual desktops. But it has some potential.